# Unstability condition for positive feedback network involving phase change

Tags: amplifier, stability, positive-feedback

For positive feedback:

\$G=\frac{A}{1-AB}\$

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback#Basic), this system is unstable for AB>1.

This condition appears to be for the cases when 'A' and 'B' have real values. But in general, A and B are complex quantities. Is there a general form of this condition for complex AB (e.g. feedback network consisting of RC phase shifters)?

I considered the possibility of |AB|>1 being the general condition. But it seems wrong since it would imply that even for AB<-1 the system is always unstable, which is wrong since the system is in negative feedback for AB<-1.

Comment: Equations are valid for real and complex numbers. For example: When AB has a magnitude of 0dB or 1 V/V gain with a 180 degree phase shift the result is -1. It's the phase of a complex number that makes it negative or positive. Take a sine wave, and shift it in time (phase shift), it will not become negative until you get to 180 degrees where it crosses the x axis.

Comment: @guitardenver How does an equation (|AB| angle AB)>1 make any sense? Its solvable only for angle(AB)=0 OR 180 (i.e. only for real AB).

Comment: There is no absolute value in the transfer function. You can add, subtract, multiply and divide complex numbers just like you can real numbers. The result of AB can be complex as well. The results of the whole transfer function (G) can be complex, it just means it has a gain and a phase shift. A and B are usually done in the Laplace (S) domain. Then you use partial fraction expansion to get it back into the time domain, usually resulting in some decaying exponentials and a steady state value. Solve the equation using algebra just like you would with real numbers, but use complex math instead.